# Best pratice to organize file and folder

Tags: php, file, directory

This is just a theorical question. I just finish to develop a php quotation system for solar panel. During the steps user is required to get a cople of images from google maps (stored those as pictures), a couple of charts picture are generated in another step and stored as well. Finally togheter with many data those picture are pulled in a pdf for final quotation. The pdf file is required to be stored as well.

Now i first decide to create one folder for each quotation and put all file inside this folder but now i realized this will end up to have too many folders once the system will be operative.

So i wonder if you guys would give me a clue if is better to keep generating a folder for each quotation (ending up with a folder that will contain as many folder as many quotation are done) or using just folder, for example images and quotation. This will cause those folder being too big though.

Customer is requiring me to keep allmpicture and quotation generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest your folders. Put folders for IDs 1 through 1000 in one folder, 1001 through 2000 in the next, and so on.

Comment: Yeah this is a good solution, i thought to that, but i really needed someone to tell me it was a good idea, thanks Ignacio.

Answer (score 1):

The way the images are stored and the way they're displayed to the user should be separated. The information about where the qutoations for each user exists should be stored in a database.

That way you can store quotations in any way you want and still have them displayed for each user. Either you could split them up by IDs as Ignacio say, or you could split them up by day, time, or anything else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actually everything is already stored in database, i'm not worried on how to track pictures, i just need to have a good folder schema though